# working mechanism of mail android app

Tags: android, push-notification, android-service, real-time-updates

I want to know the complete working mechanism of the mail apps for android.
Actually I build an android app for big data product.It has a feature which will shows the notifications (list view) .
Now I want If new notifications come in the DB It should ring a bell and in notification bar of the android phone it should show, As in case of Mail apps, as soon as we got new mail a notification comes in notification bar.

NOTE: android server which needs to be queried may not contain internet.This App works on intranet also.within a company network.(without the internet)

So I want to know the mechanism to implement this feature.

1) Whether i should run a background service which will send query to server on regular time interval.
2) Or any other services like push notification.

I just need a clear idea about working of these type of system.So that I can implement this in effective manner.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Obviously the best solutions would be to use `PushNotifications`. This is how `GMail` does it, and this is how every email app, or messaging app has to do it.

Polling the server will drain the battery, and will also make extra (unnecessary) data traffic, which is something you don't want your app to do .

You should get started here : [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). In my opinion it is very easy to setup, and I recommend using GCM, instead of all the other alternatives like Parse and so on.

Comment: nice but what If my android server uses only intranet. Its not accessible to internet.How this thing will work?

Comment: it will work. as long as your device and your server, can communicate with the Google Servers, just to send the PUSH, it will work.

Comment: for communicating with google server we need internet right? what if only intranet facility is there.the android server is not accessable to internet.

Comment: if the internet is not accessible for the mobile device, you won't be able to receive the push notification. (push is basically a low-level polling done by the Android OS to the Google servers)

Comment: So what is the alternative for this problem? If neither the server nor android phone is not connected to the internet.

Comment: In this case I guess you'll have to go and do the polling.